# Are there any bus companies that take bikes and go between Washington DC and Philadelphia?

Tags: public-transportation

Some googling turns up a chinatown bus company ("focus transit"), but I called and they no longer go to Philly.  Anyone else taking bikes in the luggage bay as of summer 2015?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most inter-city trains still take bikes.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that Focus Transit actually goes between DC and Philly still.  The guy on the other end of the phone didn't know what he was talking about when I called.  They take bikes.